# Do images inside a nuxt project affect it's bundle size?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have a question, because the documentation of nuxt hasn't answered me that specific point. I have some images used in sliders and background etc. These images are inside the assets folder. I am working on the optimization of my project, therefore I want to know what impact do this images have on my bundled code, ready to deploy on production.

I would appreciate your input on this...

Comment: not quite clear what you mean by bundle size

Comment: sorry, I'm talking about the result of the `npm build`

Comment: still dont understand.Obv images should be on server otherwise they wont be able to serve. Images remains images

Comment: before I deploy I build the project, right? so, I'm asking if the images that are inside my folders are getting optimized, while being concluded in the built result. and if having too many images there will affect the speed of this built.